# scraping a table from multiple table wikipedia

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was trying to scrape table from this url
[wikipedia](https://id.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demografi_Indonesia#Jumlah_penduduk_menurut_provinsi). There are 5 different tables there. But my target is the first table shown there. It has not much identity there, that table only contains this identity

```
class="wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter"
```

which the other table have the same identity. I saw some source that i should take it by `id`. But this table has no `id`.

### This

```
My_table = soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable sortable'})
```

this is how i scrape it currently

### Question

How do we choose only that table without `id`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select the first table using `soup.find_all('table')[1]`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 

url = "https://id.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demografi_Indonesia#Jumlah_penduduk_menurut_provinsi"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
table = soup.find_all('table')[1]
rows = table.find_all('tr')
row_list = list()

for tr in rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text for i in td]
    row_list.append(row)

print(row_list[1:])
```

Comment: hi thank you so much for your respond, i would like to know how to use this in code.

Comment: You're welcome - I have edited my answer with the code sample.

Answer (score 3):

Get all tables and store in array then get table from [0] index. In this way, you can extract first table without any id.

Comment: hi thank you so much for your respond, can you show me how to modify the code

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it:

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://id.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demografi_Indonesia#Jumlah_penduduk_menurut_provinsi'
df_list = pd.read_html(url)
df = df_list[1]
print(df)
```

Comment: Any table in in link with df = df_list[2] or df = df_list[3] or df = df_list[4] or df = df_list[5]

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://id.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demografi_Indonesia#Jumlah_penduduk_menurut_provinsi'
list = pd.read_html(url)
dd = list[1]
```